# How to remove eclipse darkest dark theme?

Tags: eclipse, themes

Unable to remove eclipse darkest dark theme. I tried to install this for latest eclipse oxygen and it got installed successfully, but now I am unable to remove it.
How to remove a theme from eclipse?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you not like it ;-)

Comment: @saikosen I liked it but unable to digest as I am used to white theme... :-)

Comment: Fair enough mate :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Goto Help -> Eclipse Market Place

A child window will open showing available plugins in Eclipse Market Place.
Above we will find a tab named "Installed"
Go to 'Installed' tab. It will show the list of installed or associated plugins with current copy of eclipse.

Against 'darkest dark theme' (beside installed button)  we will find a drop down where we get option to uninstall.

Comment: thanks, what a useless waste of time the Darkest Dark theme is!
dark background plus dark fonts, not the smartest idea in the universe.

Comment: @DavemM sorry to hear you had a bad experience with Darkest Dark. Of course, dark fonts on dark backgrounds are useless. We test quite a few editors with this theme, but it's possible that we missed some. If you could spare a minute to tell us what editor you experienced this with, we'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: New trend seems to be going Dark.

Comment: I did automatic updates today, and DevStyle changed all my settings and startup (to darkest theme) without even asking - does anybody really like bright text on black background, with difficult to see icons?. Very annoyed. It took a while to figure out what had changed and how to disable it. No option in Preferences (under DevStyle -> Color Themes) to disable the plugin or even put things back to Eclipse standard (Workbench theme list). It change the icons to either pastel or primary colors - how do I put them back to Eclipse standard default?

Comment: "DevStyle (includes Darkest Theme)" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it. Sigh :(

Comment: Preferences -> General -> Appearance: Enable Theming: Theme=Classic. This disables the DevStyle themes. Reference: https://www.genuitec.com/tech/darkest-dark/

Comment: Didn't work for me, i get this error: **"DevStyle (includes Darkest Dark Theme)" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it. The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.**. The only way to remove it was by removing it manually with its dependencies (angular ide) from plugins/feature folders

Answer (score 11):

Just navigate to Preferences > General > Appearance. Choose "Classic" for "Theme" and hit "Apply and Close". You may have to restart eclipse.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to go back to the original theme, but it doesn't actually remove the DD theme from Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse, reset Appearance:
  Preferences > General > Appearance, Just Restore defaults and apply/close. 
If still no change then do the same thing to child options under Appearance one by one.

Answer (score 1):

It was the WebClipse CI 9 update (dated 201711281859) which automatically replaced the default Eclipse Classic theme preferences and startup dialog with the Dark theme, without asking, and without giving the user an option to disable it or put it back the way it was.